# Why isn't forEach function letting me returning an object or even just passing it out from the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, foreach

I'm trying do make a simple app which shows and save your favorites (let's call them easily "object"). I thought to do it like: 
get the favorite from vuex,
find the favorite in the array of possible favorites,
manage my favorite as I want.

name value is correct, I already know vuex state.
Elenco is an array got by a JSON, it works because I use it in a v-for and in other two functions (none uses forEach function).
the if statement works good otherwise it won't show the first "i".

```
let name = this.$store.state.favTime.id;
console.log(name);
Elenco.forEach(element => {
    if(element.name === name){
        var i = element;
        console.log(i); //element
    }
});
console.log(i); //undefined
```

I would like just to access to that object so that i can manipulate it but i can't because it's undefined.

(Hope to have followed correctly these guidelines and hope my english is enough goood to make it understandable, thanks).

Comment: You have defined `        var i = element; inside forEach and trying to access outside its scope. Declare it outside of forEach
`

Comment: Declaring `i` before the forEach would make it be in scope after the loop, but it would contain the last element in Elenco, not the one with the matching name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `find` instead of `forEach` for your use case, if available.

```
const name = this.$store.state.favTime.id;
const favourite = Elenco.find(element => element.name === name)
console.log(favourite)
```

Comment: This is functionally different from what OP's code does. OP's code will store the last match in i, your code will return the first match. If that is what OP needs we both don't know, but your answer fails to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access that variable after the for loop, declare it before the loop:

```
var i;
Elenco.forEach(element => {
    if(element.name === name){
        i = element;
        console.log(i); //element
    }
});
console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
let name = this.$store.state.favTime.id;

let elem = Elenco.find(element => {
    return element.name === name
});

console.log(element);
```

> The find() method returns the value of the **first element** in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.

if you want to find the last element, you can [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array :

```
let name = this.$store.state.favTime.id;

let elem = [...Elenco].reverse().find(element => {
    return element.name === name
});

console.log(element);
```

Comment: This is functionally different from what OP's code does. OP's code will store the last match in `i`, your code will return the first match. If that is what OP needs we both don't know, but your answer fails to explain that.

Comment: @connexo you're right, i updated the answer to match the OP's case.

Comment: Still you don't explicitly state that your first approach will return the first match.

Comment: @connexo i didn't think it was necessary since i put the link to MDN of `find()`,

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of local and global scope of variables. Variable created inside for loops have local reference, so declare them globally.

```
var name = "Johnny";

var Elenco = [
  {
    name: "Jack Torrance",
    age: 50,
    eyeColor: "blue"
  },
  {
    name: "Toni",
    age: 8,
    eyeColor: "blue"
  },
  {
    name: "Johnny",
    age: 50,
    eyeColor: "blue"
  }
];
var i = new Array();
Elenco.forEach(element => {
    if(element.name === name){
        i.push(element);
        console.log(i); //element
    }
});
console.log(i);
```

[image: Screenshot of the console]